# Android Navigation Component - Why add arguments in the navigation graph?

Tags: java, android, android-architecture-navigation, android-navigation-graph

I've been following CodingWithMitch's [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IEO2X5OU3MY) (and [github code](https://github.com/mitchtabian/Navigation-Components-Example)) to Navigation Component, but used Java instead of Kotlin. That hasn't brought any issues however.

My question is, without using Safe Args, what is the point to adding arguments in the `nav_graph.xml`.

In this example, `SpecifyAmountFragment` requires a String argument from the previous Fragment, called `ChooseRecipientFragment`:

Design View of `nav_graph.xml`:
[image: Design view connecting ChooseRecipientFragment ----> specifyAmmountFragment ----> confirmationFragment]

Code snippet from the `nav_graph.xml`:

```xml
<fragment
        android:id="@+id/specifyAmountFragment"
        android:name="com.asfartz.navigation_component_basics.SpecifyAmountFragment"
        android:label="fragment_specify_amount"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_specify_amount">

        <argument android:name="recipient"
            app:argType="string" />

        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_specifyAmountFragment_to_confirmationFragment"
            app:destination="@id/confirmationFragment"
            app:enterAnim="@anim/slide_in_right"
            app:exitAnim="@anim/slide_out_left"
            app:popEnterAnim="@anim/slide_in_left"
            app:popExitAnim="@anim/slide_out_right"
            app:popUpTo="@id/mainFragment"
            app:popUpToInclusive="false" />
    </fragment>
```

Java code:

```java
public class SpecifyAmountFragment extends Fragment {

    private NavController navController;
    private Button bSend, bCancel;
    private String recipient;
    private TextView tvRecipient;
    private TextInputEditText inputAmount;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_specify_amount, container, false);
        bSend = view.findViewById(R.id.send_btn);
        bCancel = view.findViewById(R.id.cancel_btn);
        tvRecipient = view.findViewById(R.id.recipient);
        inputAmount = view.findViewById(R.id.input_amount);

        recipient = getArguments().getString("recipient");

        String messagge = "Sending money to " + recipient;
        tvRecipient.setText(messagge);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        navController = Navigation.findNavController(view);

        bSend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(inputAmount.getText())) {
                    Money money = new Money(new BigDecimal(inputAmount.getText().toString()));
                    Bundle b = new Bundle();
                    b.putString("recipient", recipient);
                    b.putParcelable("money", money);

                    navController.navigate(R.id.action_specifyAmountFragment_to_confirmationFragment, b);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Enter an amount", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });

        bCancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (getActivity() != null) {
                    getActivity().onBackPressed();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Activity is null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I'm receiving the bundle in OnCreateView, from which I'm taking the required String argument that I've declared in the `nav_graph.xml`. And later on, I'm sending this data forward in another bundle (in the `bSend.setOnClickListener(...)`).

If I comment out all the `<argument>` tags and run the app again, the app will still work as it should (receiving the data from one fragment and passing it to another). There is no validation, so why add these tags at all, besides for clarity maybe?

Answer (score 0):

When using Navigation architecture component, you are not suppose to use 
`recipient = getArguments().getString("recipient");`
Instead, you should use generated class of the destination which should be `SpecifyAmountFragmentArgs` and get your data this way: 
`SpecifyAmountFragment.fromBundle(Pass arguments here).getRecipient` which will provide type safety.

Comment: I believe you're referring to the SafeArgs plugin, which generates these classes (```ConfirmationFragmentArgs```)  for each destination. But I'm asking if the ```<argument>``` part in the .xml is of any use without having SafeArgs

Comment: Hi what to pass here: (Pass arguments here) can u explain in detail @SamirSpahic